# Validity of GhostHunters and other ghost shows on cable

Tags: ghosts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any scientific evidence at all that suggests ghosts exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/788/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-at-all-that-suggests-ghosts-exist)

My wife often watches Ghost Hunters on SyFy.  What explanations are there for some of the shows where the 'investigators' claim a property may have 'spirits' of some kind occupying the area?

Comment: My answer to this question [Is there any scientific reason at all to think EMF detectors would be able to detect ghosts?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/is-there-any-scientific-reason-at-all-to-think-emf-detectors-would-be-able-to-det) covers most of what you're asking, I think. In essence, there are no explanations given and many of the actual "eerie" phenomena are likely faked.

Comment: "What explanations are there for some of the shows" - in 5 letters, m.o.n.e.y. It's just a TV-age carney con. Unfortunately, as P.T.Barnum (did NOT) say, "There a sucker born every minute".

Comment: The investigators don't make the claims, the property owners do.  And places that are known as haunted places have been that way before these shows came along.   If you're asking whether or not the claims are valid, that's different.