# Did a poltergeist move furniture around in this CCTV footage?

Tags: ghosts

I found [this article](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/watch-evil-ghost-hurl-furniture-5945659) on The Mirror web-site.

> Terrifying CCTV footage has emerged online of the moment an 'evil ghost' appears to attack a hotel by throwing around furniture in front of horrified witnesses.
>
> In the bizarre clip, a man is seen standing in what looks like the hotel's lobby before he inexplicably makes a run for it out of the room.
>
> [...]
>
> So far, YouTube viewers seem pretty convinced by the footage, which was uploaded to the video site by Night Ghost House, but little information is available about the clip, including the location and when it was filmed.

Is this staged? It looks pretty sophisticated, maybe it's from a Hollywood movie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do ghosts exist?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/788/do-ghosts-exist)

Comment: What exactly do you see in the video that cannot be explained with very simple trickery?

Comment: For clarity sake, which question are you asking? The one in the title or the one at the end of the question text. They are very different questions that require very different methods of address.

Comment: @DampeS8N I don't see how they are different enough to require separate answers. One asks whether a ghost did it, the other asks whether it was staged (i.e. whether the ghost did not do it).

Comment: The article now clearly states: > "However, it has since emerged that the clip is actually taken from the trailer for Malaysian film Bangunan".

Comment: When I made the post, I mentioned that it was clearly a clickbait site with a clickbait heading, it got edited out. It seems that maybe it should not have been edited out because apparantly that site has so little journalistic integrity that they publish movie trailers as legit. I know that clickbait sounds unprofessional, but how otherwise are you to convey the idea that they post anything as long as it is sensational?

Comment: @Apeforce: [The Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_Mirror) is a long-running tabloid newspaper. Its reputation may be a good reason for your skepticism shields to be secured before reading, but it is not evidence that the claims are false - that would be ad hominem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The CCTV footage was mistaken with an actual movie called Bangunan (2015). This is the [official trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe_5qfulIZM) of the movie:

[image]